# in JAVA - How to insert json data into a nested json property?

Tags: java, arrays, json, jdbc

I have this code i have on my java server:

```
JSONArray resultJson = new JSONArray();
try{
    ConnectToDB();
    stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    m_ResultSet = stmt.executeQuery();
    resultJson = FromDBToJSON.toJSON(m_ResultSet);
    }
```

I am getting this result:

```
id: 1,
dest_country: "England",
fname: "Duncan",
lname: "Hurley",
address: "xyz"
},
{
id: 2,
dest_country: "England",
fname: "Duncan",
lname: "Hurley",
address: "xyz"
},
{
id: 3,
dest_country: "Israel",
fname: "Duncan",
lname: "Hurley",
address: "xyz"
},
{
id: 4,
dest_country: "USA",
fname: "Duncan",
lname: "Hurley",
address: "xyz"
},
```

I need to put all the user data (which is fname, lname, address) into a nested property, for exanple like this:

```
{
    id : 2,
    dest_country: "England",
    user: {
        fname: "Duncan",
        lname: "Hurley",
        address: "xyz"
    }
}
```

how can this be achieved?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your classes will have to be structured like this:

```
class User{
    public string fname;
    public string lname;
    public string address;
}

class ResultType{
    public int id;
    public string dest_country;
    public User user;
}
```

This should generate the results you are looking for when parsed to JSON.
The json is based on the current class structure so the user that you want to be in a nested property has to be generated from a prooperty which is an object containing that data.

Another way would be to reconstruct your json data afterwards but that's not as tidy. Like so:

```
result.each(function(){
    this.user = { fname: this.fname, lname: this.lname, address: this.address };
});
```

Comment: are you referring here to js? I need this to be done on the server side.

Comment: The second part is js but the class structure refers to the Java classes. If it has to be done server side you should be looking to structure the classes so that the data is generated in the structure you want  otherwise it becomes labour intensive and not very maintainable/reusable to modify the output.

Comment: ok, but if so, it means that I still need to map all columns from the ResultSet to each property. or is there an "automatic" way to do this?

Comment: If the classes are structured as shown it should output the structure you are looking for by default and wouldn't require any further changes using js or anything else.

Comment: @Dhunt , how can i save this object using spring and hibernate. Am getting nested JSON

Answer (score 0):

Use the [**javax.json.JsonObject**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html), try the following code:

```
JSONArray resultJson = new JSONArray();
try{
ConnectToDB();
stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
m_ResultSet = stmt.executeQuery();
while (m_ResultSet.next()) {
  JsonObject userObject= Json.createObjectBuilder()
    .add("fname", m_ResultSet.getString("fname")
    .add("lname", m_ResultSet.getString("lname")
    .add("adress", m_ResultSet.getString("adress").build();

 JsonObject resultJson = Json.createObjectBuilder()
  .add("id", m_ResultSet.getInt("id"))
  .add("dest_country", m_ResultSet.getString("dest_country"))
  .add("user", userObject).build();
}
```

That should do it.